# Entity Framework 5 Code First. How to specify the tables that I would like to drop?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I want to drop some tables and create again following my models design. But the CodeFirst never do it, keeping trying to apply the changes that I did, but for some reason he can't.
The Designs of models class is ok but the tables on SQL is not and thats why and want to drop and recreate again.

I did some changes on model and especially with keys and Foreign Keys.
So why I think if I could set which tables I would like to drop, code first will Understand my new implementation.

**Erro output update-database**

```
PM> update-database -verbose -force
Using StartUp project 'WebTier'.
Using NuGet project 'Target.Data.SqlServer'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Target.Data.Model.TacticalGoal' and 'Target.Data.Model.ICB'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.AssociationTypeMappingGenerator.GenerateIndependentAssociationType(EdmAssociationType associationType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.AssociationTypeMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmAssociationType associationType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.GenerateAssociationTypes(EdmModel model, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_CodeFirstModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.GetMigrator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Target.Data.Model.TacticalGoal' and 'Target.Data.Model.ICB'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to downgrade your migrations. Going back to your past migrations which were created before your "create table" migrations, will solve your problem. You can write this command in Package-Manager Console:

```
Update-Database –TargetMigration: yourPreviousMigrationName
```

After that you can create again your tables with new forms.

Comment: It looks work in my case, except that EF will try to apply the sames migrations. There is a way to remove or delete migrations?

Comment: After going back to the past migration, go to your Solution Exploler->Migrations folder, try right clicking and deleting the newest migrations than your current migration. Then it can't be able to apply same migrations.

Comment: And what about automatic migrations? These are not in there and Code first want to install them.

Comment: You can learn details about using automatic migrations in: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx